# Trouble interpreting CTR_DRBG test vector results

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, test-vectors

I've implemented a CTR_DRBG random number generator according to NIST SP 800-90A Rev. 1 and I am now testing it with test vectors provided in NIST CAVS 14.3 (drbgvectors_no_reseed\CTR_DRBG.txt).

Starting from the very first example of [AES-128 no df]:

```
[AES-128 no df]
[PredictionResistance = False]
[EntropyInputLen = 256]
[NonceLen = 0]
[PersonalizationStringLen = 0]
[AdditionalInputLen = 0]
[ReturnedBitsLen = 512]

COUNT = 0
EntropyInput = ce50f33da5d4c1d3d4004eb35244b7f2cd7f2e5076fbf6780a7ff634b249a5fc
Nonce = 
PersonalizationString = 
** INSTANTIATE:
    Key = 96b20ff35faaf1b2e27f53e4f6a3f2a8
    V   = cef7f49e164d55eaf957348dc3fb5b84

AdditionalInput = 
** GENERATE (FIRST CALL):
    Key = 2e8bf07c5a29b97633576a7c4d5343dd
    V   = 3f93dbc9dc724d654f5f2a45b818c7ec

AdditionalInput = 
ReturnedBits = 6545c0529d372443b392ceb3ae3a99a30f963eaf313280f1d1a1e87f9db373d361e75d18018266499cccd64d9bbb8de0185f213383080faddec46bae1f784e5a
** GENERATE (SECOND CALL):
    Key = a103e1669b0641cae87caab70a741bf1
    V   = fbe9d7c15217c737b408e31679170140
```

After instantiation, internal state (Key and V) are both what they are supposed to be.

Then I call Generate and the generated pseudorandom output is:

```
9400BE2ED57BBD55EEDC02E47F7B5F1AED21140F132570D455829D2E8292B9D79A6C224E730E3F31F2BFF613516294BCA1D5629332A3BC1A90C9C7ACB3459609
```

The internal state now matches what is written under GENERATE (FIRST CALL).

Calling the generate function once again, I now get the same pseudorandom number as written above under ReturnedBits and also the correct internal state.

This is my confusion: Why is the Generate function called twice to get a single output string of pseudorandom bits?

Following the Generate process (NIST SP 800-90A Rev. 1, chapter 9.3.1), Generate_algorithm would only be called twice if the first call returned that the reseed counter exceeded the maximum value and a reseed was required. But this should not be the case, as we just reset the reseed counter to 1 during instantiation. What am I missing?